# como poner slider con más duración

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

tengo esto https://crucerosfluviales.es/old-version/site/js/core.min.js y esto https://crucerosfluviales.es/old-version/site/js/script.js.

Lo que pasa es que no he logrado decifrar dos cosas en ese codigo.
1. que puedas cambiar el ancho de los slider
2. que pueda cambiar la duración de cada slider

agradezco su ayuda

```
<section class="section text-center">
        <!-- Slick Carousel-->
        <div class="slick-wrap" id="slider">
          <div class="slick-slider slick-style-1" data-arrows="true" data-autoplay="true" data-loop="true" data-dots="true" data-swipe="true" data-xs-swipe="true" data-sm-swipe="false" data-items="1" data-sm-items="3" data-md-items="3" data-lg-items="3" data-center-mode="true" data-lightgallery="group-slick">
          <div class="item">
              <div class="slick-slide-inner">
                <div class="slick-slide-caption"><img class="thumb-ann__image" src="images/slider/aurora-boreal-noche-estrellas1.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="664"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="slick-slide-inner">
                <div class="slick-slide-caption"><img class="thumb-ann__image" src="images/slider/laponia-papa-noel.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="664"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="slick-slide-inner">
                <div class="slick-slide-caption"><img class="thumb-ann__image" src="images/slider/la-casa-de-papa-noel-rovaniemi.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="664"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="slick-slide-inner">
                <div class="slick-slide-caption"><img class="thumb-ann__image" src="images/slider/rovaniemi-capital-de-laponia-papa-noel.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="664"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
<section>
```

Comment: Qué librería estás usando para el carousel? Slick? Owl? Lightgallery? Pues veo todas tres en el archivo de scripts que compartes, y ninguno hace referencia a la velocidad, debes agregarla según la librería que tengas. Por favor revisa: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: utilizo carousel slik

Comment: Slick es relativamente fácil de configurar, puedes modificar tamaño y duración de los elementos. Por favor provee un código ejecutable, pues haciendo pruebas no pude replicar el slider con el código que nos compartes. Mientras, puedes revisar la documentación oficial de Slick https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/